# How to use a ternary with a ListView within a PageView

Tags: flutter

I have the following code which displays a ListView that is inside a PageView (the Expanded is inside a Column) :

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: rollRows.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return rosterViewCard(rollRows[index]);
    },
  ),
)
```

I would like to test rollRows.length to see if it equals 1, and if so, instead of displaying the ListView, I want to display a text saying "No jobs to display".

I tried this:

```
Expanded(
  child: rollRows == 1
    ? [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            'No shifts to display',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: kBodyText),
          ),
        ),              
      ]
    : [  
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: rollRows.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return rosterViewCard(rollRows[index]);
          },
        ),
      ]
)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

I guess I'm putting the ternary condition in the wrong place, but not sure where to do it. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the `[` and `]` from the ternary condition.

The `Expanded` widget takes in a widget as the `child` property. But currently, you are passing a `List` by using `[` & `]`. Removing these square brackets will remove the error.

```
Expanded(
  child: rollRows == 1
    ? 
        Center(
          child: Text(
            'No shifts to display',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: kBodyText),
          ),
        )             
      
    :   
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: rollRows.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return rosterViewCard(rollRows[index]);
          },
        ),
      
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one, i think it's help for you..!!

```
rollRows.length == 1
        ? Center(
            child: Text(
              'No shifts to display',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: kBodyText),
            ),
          )
        : Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: rollRows.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return rosterViewCard(rollRows[index]);
              },
            ),
          )
```